# Should questions mostly aimed at the devs be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example:

- [Why the blender browser plugin is not updated?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18571/599)
- [Why blender is not saving used Images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18096/599)

These questions ask things about the design choices and decisions involved in making blender to which probably only the developers can give a complete answer.

I know that this probably is out of our [current scope](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> The Blender Stack Exchange site is for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.

But we do have some developers who are pretty active on the site, in particular [ideasman42♦](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55/ideasman42) and [brecht](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/242/brecht). Not to mention the many community developers who develop blender in their free time.

Since in the past these kinds of questions seem to be asked in places like the mailing list and IRC, it's hard to find existing answers.

If these questions were allowed on SE, they could stick around and not be buried in some long lost mailing list thread.

Should we expand our scope to allow more development oriented questions?
What do the developer users think of this?

Comment: I see no problem allowing question like those. If it turns out that these types of questions don't get much activity, then we can at a later time come back and look at our position.

Comment: @David As far as activity goes, here's [another one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18608/599). I agree, and this seems to go with the whole "open development" thing. There are probably lots of questions in this category that can be answered by anyone after a look at the tracker or code, without needing to be a official blender foundation developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange works really well for *technical* support, as long as you're not trying to outsource your entire customer support channel to Stack Exchange. Customer support includes things like feature requests and bug reporting (for Blender), or up-and-coming product release discussions. That doesn't belong here.

But if the internal team is here to answer your deeper-workings or development-centric questions that help you get your work done, then yes… I think that would be a good addition to this site.